# docker-compose up clear screen

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there a way to make `docker-compose up` don't clear terminal after build and before run ?

I want to see the output made before running the services, but it will always clear screen and I can't find any switches to make it maintain the previous output.

*EDIT*

Here's an example of the screen clearing happening:

https://asciinema.org/a/0VUPSfbaEZqG8Ha1dG7YCmNuA

Please notice it clearing screen 2 times: first I do a docker-compose up, then it begins starting the app (at aprox. 00:08), it clears the screen and says "starting compilation in watch mode" (at 00:10) and finally it clears screen again in 00:11 saying "File change detected. Stating incremental compilation".

Comment: what is the output of your attempt to `docker-compose up` ? As much as I know, this should be the solution to keep the terminal running, unless it fails or has some extra configuration in `docker-compose.yaml`

Comment: The output is the build, then it clears screen, then it shows app output. I want it not to clear the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launching

```
docker-compose up
```

does not make the terminal clear. Reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/).

In this specific case, the problem resides inside the launched container, where the `nest start --watch` command is run. To prevent the app clearing the screen, run with `--preserveWatchOutput`.

Comment: Yes and then I can use docker-compose logs to see the output. But what I really want is to make a non-detached run that doesn't clear the terminal. Is that possible ?

Comment: maybe you can try with the `--attach` option

Comment: It still clears screen after build and before showing app output...

Comment: I cannot replicate your situation with one of my images. If i run `docker-compose up --build` (to force rebuilding of images) both build and app output are shown without clearing the screen.

Comment: See my edit. I included a video of the screen clearing as it happens.

Comment: I'm not super expert about yarn, but from what I see I think the issue may be related to the app rather than to docker-compose. Indeed, when the docker is started (green *done* appears), the screen is not cleared. It is cleared when `nest start --watch` is executed. The screen is cleared and the app is compiled. Maybe there is some additional option that you can add when launching that command to avoid clearing the screen?

Comment: Yes there is... --preserveWatchOutput. It's a NestJs specific switch. I found it because of your comment. Do you want to edit the answer to include this answer so I can accept it ?

Comment: certainly, but I also suggest to update the title and the text (where appropriate) of your question to achieve a better focus about the problem and better help other people

Comment: Ok but I only saw the problem was in nest after your comments. So I think the initial title was appropriate. But I'm open to suggestions. What would you think a good name would be ?

Comment: well I think that after discovering the problem a better question (also for documentation purposes) would be "how to launch nest without clearing the screen" but you're also right, the initial question was appropriate without knowing the issue

Comment: I think I'll maintain it, for the sake of coherence. I think changing to include nest would confuse the readers more than help